# C++ compile time check if method exists in template type

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template that calls a member function. How do I check with `static_assert` that the method exists?

```
struct A {

};

struct B {
    int foo() { return 42; } };

template <typename T> struct D {
    static_assert(/* T has foo */, "T needs foo for reasons");

    int bar() {
       return t.foo();
    }

    T t; };

int main() {
    D<A> d;

    std::cout << d.bar() << std::endl;

    return 0; }
```

I know this will just generate a compiler error that A does not have foo but I would like to check and give a better error output using `static_assert`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to write a template to check for a function's existence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence)

Comment: I think a compiler error is fine if it's clear. And `error: no member named 'foo' in 'A'` seems pretty clear.

Comment: C++20 solves this with concepts, if you’re going to upgrade to that when it’s out.

Comment: There is [experimental support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) for this already. Very easy to implement your own version.

Answer (score 8):

Since you use `static_assert` I assert that you are using at least C++11. This allows to write something like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class ...Ts>
struct voider{
    using type = void;
};

template<class T, class = void>
struct has_foo : std::false_type{};

template<class T>
struct has_foo<T, typename voider<decltype(std::declval<T>().foo())>::type> : std::true_type{};
```

And you just use static field `value` (`has_foo<your_type>::value`) - if it's true then your type has function `foo`.

Comment: Two comments: 1. In C++17 you can use [`std::void_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) and even before that you can write `voider` somewhat more nicely. 2. You can also use more type traits to ensure that *calling* `T::foo` returns an `int` or something convertible.

Comment: @bartop I do not understand the use of `struct voider`. Why does `struct has_foo<T, typename decltype(std::declval<T>().foo())> : std::true_type{};` not work.

Answer (score 1):

[Constraint templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) has been a **long**  discussion - ever since 2005 or so - on std forums. But the outcome has yet to wait til C++20.

Comment: Could you write an example how to use those constraints to achieve what OP is looking for?

Comment: The syntax is awkward now. It wasn't supposed to be like that. Either a named concept or an inline nasty concept: `template<typename T> requires requires(T t){ {t.foo()} -> std::same_as<int>;} struct D{};` the double `requires` is ugly inline syntax. For `std::same_as` include `<concepts>`.