# How to detect a noexcept method using SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, methods, sfinae, noexcept

I'm asking about a variation of a (popular) question - detecting the existence of a method of a class.

I've read many answers here in SO, and most of the (post C++17) solutions look like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55191505/c-compile-time-check-if-method-exists-in-template-type):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class ...Ts>
struct voider{
    using type = void;
};

template<class T, class = void>
struct has_foo : std::false_type{};

template<class T>
struct has_foo<T, typename voider<decltype(std::declval<T>().foo())>::type> : std::true_type{};
```

Basically, we're letting the compiler decide using a "trick" : 
if the expression `std::declval<T>().foo()` is well-formed, 
then `decltype(std::declval<T>().foo())` doesn't produce a compiler-error, 
then the compiler "prefers" `has_foo<T, typename voider<decltype(...)>>::type` since it doesn't need to replace the second template type  with a default type.

great, but how can we combine `noexcept` with it? 
I've tried many ways but it seems most techniques (including `decltype(declval<type>.my_func())`) 
only care about the name, return type and the argument types and not about the noexcept.

Comment: Why not just use the `noexcept` operator then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with the help of [`noexpect` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept) (since C++11).

> The noexcept operator performs a compile-time check that returns true if an expression is declared to not throw any exceptions.

e.g.

```
template<class T>
struct has_foo<T, 
               typename voider<decltype(std::declval<T>().foo()),
                               std::enable_if_t<noexcept(std::declval<T>().foo())>
                              >::type
              > : std::true_type{};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lXuw9NNmAlM2uht7)