# noexcept + declval fail to compile under MSVC

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, compiler-errors, sfinae

I'm trying to implement the answer I got to my SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59908697/how-to-detect-a-noexcept-method-using-sfinae):
My goal is to detect the existence of `void cancel() noexcept` method in a template class `T`.
here is my minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T, class = void>
struct has_cancel : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct has_cancel<T,
    typename std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().cancel()),
    typename std::enable_if_t<noexcept(std::declval<T>().cancel())>
    >
> : std::true_type {};

void print_has_cancel(std::true_type) {
    std::cout << "cancel found" << std::endl;
}

void print_has_cancel(std::false_type) {
    std::cout << "cancel not found" << std::endl;
}

struct A{

};

struct B {
    void cancel(){}
};

struct C {
    int cancel() noexcept {}
};

struct D{
    void cancel() noexcept {}
};

int main(){
    print_has_cancel(has_cancel<A>());
    print_has_cancel(has_cancel<B>());
    print_has_cancel(has_cancel<C>());
    print_has_cancel(has_cancel<D>());
    return 0;
}
```

output from Visual studio community 2019:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: cpp_sandbox, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>cpp_sandbox.cpp
1>C:\Users\David Haim\source\repos\cpp_sandbox\cpp_sandbox\cpp_sandbox.cpp(10,1): error C2228:  left of '.cancel' must have class/struct/union
1>C:\Users\David Haim\source\repos\cpp_sandbox\cpp_sandbox\cpp_sandbox.cpp(10,1): message :  type is '_Add_reference<_Ty,void>::_Rvalue'
1>C:\Users\David Haim\source\repos\cpp_sandbox\cpp_sandbox\cpp_sandbox.cpp(10,19): error C2056:  illegal expression
1>Done building project "cpp_sandbox.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

After some research, the problem is with the grammar `noexcept(std::declval<type>().something())` - MSVC refuses to understand this line.

1) why is MSVC complaining? is the bug in the code or in the compiler?

2) how can I still make it compile?

Comment: I believe something, not implementation in VS yet. However, the old SIFANE trick could help maybe ? See [this](https://rextester.com/OUFRKX10264)

Comment: @P0W it doesn't detect if `cancel` is noexcept though. I'm fine with any version of the standard as long the trick can also detect noexcept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSVC doesn't have a problem with the syntax itself. It just seems to assume that SFINAE does not apply in this case, so substituting `void` as type gives the error. Why or whether there is any support for this in the standard, I don't know at the moment (but I doubt it).

This can be resolved easily by moving the `noexcept` condition from the declaration into the definition of the `struct`, so that it will never be substituted if the first `decltype` is ill-formed (i.e. if `.cancel()` doesn't exist at all) and SFINAE kicked in:

```
template<class T>
struct has_cancel<T,
    typename std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().cancel())    >
> : std::bool_constant<noexcept(std::declval<T>().cancel())> {};
```

Comment: I looked up https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t and found this: "Until CWG 1558 (a C++14 defect), unused parameters in alias templates were not guaranteed to ensure SFINAE and could be ignored".

Comment: @Frodyne It does not seem though that this is what MSVC considers. It still produces the same error even if the `void_t` is removed and only a simple `enable_if_t` is used: https://godbolt.org/z/W3gT7T