# With C++17 only, Is it possible to create a macro which accepts class and method name and returns true if such a method exists in the class?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

With C++ 20 concepts we can write smth like:

```
#define has_method(CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME) \ // Can be generalized of course, but it's just to illustrate the idea
    []<typename TEMPLATE_ARG>()             \
    {                                       \
        return requires{ std::declval<TEMPLATE_ARG>().METHOD_NAME(); }; \
    }.template operator()<CLASS_NAME>()
```

And then use it like that:

```
int main()
{
    struct S{
        void call_1();
        void call_2();
        void call_3();
        void call_4();
        };
    static_assert(has_method(S, call_1)); // OK
    static_assert(has_method(S, call_2)); // OK
    static_assert(has_method(S, call_3)); // OK
    static_assert(has_method(S, call_4)); // OK
    static_assert(has_method(S, call_5)); // Error
}
```

Is there any way I can implement `has_method` macro without concepts (i.e with C++17 only)?

To make it more clear: I need a macro which can accept class and method name and I want to use such a macro inside constexpr context just like a constexpr function. Standard SFINAE implementation requires to create at least two template structures which makes it difficult (or impossible) to put all of that into one macro. So my question whether or not it is actually impossible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ compile time check if method exists in template type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55191505/c-compile-time-check-if-method-exists-in-template-type)

Comment: How would you do that? I need a macro which accepts class and method name.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/templated-check-for-the-existence-of-a-class-member-function#257382

Comment: You would need to create a structure to use "standard" SFINAE. How can you put all of that into one macro to use it inside "if constexpr"?

Comment: Why on earth does it have to be "in one macro"? Some of the most widely used, production quality software libraries use details in their headers that are not themselves hidden behind a macro (even though their macros use them). This requirement seems strange.

Comment: By "in one macro" I mean an ability to create a "function like" something, which can return bool value (acts like a constexpr function). What's the alternative? Create a different "SFINAE-structures" each time we want to check a method existence?

Comment: @NicolBolas This is not a duplicate. This question seeks a solution parametrized by both the class AND the method. The linked answers can only check a presence of pre-defined, hardcoded method, that is not what the author requests here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, though it does require a macro AFAIK, but you seem to not mind that.

We of course need some SFINAE context because that is the only place where we are allowed to write syntax errors. But creating in-place templates is tricky because local classes cannot contain them, so even `if(class { /* template magic */}x; <something with x>)` C++17 feature won't help much.

Since C++14 there is one feature that I am aware of which does allow defining types with templated methods inside an expression - templated lambdas.

I took inspiration from [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) with overloaded set and [SFINAE test using overloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/templated-check-for-the-existence-of-a-class-member-function#257382):

```cpp
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
// explicit deduction guide (not needed as of C++20)
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;
 
#define HAS_METHOD(class_type,method)                                               \
overloaded {                                                                        \
    [](auto* arg, decltype(&std::decay_t<decltype(*arg)>::method) ptr) constexpr    \
        { return true;},                                                            \
    [](auto* arg, ...) constexpr                                                    \
        { return false;}                                                            \
}((class_type*)nullptr,nullptr)                                                                         

#include <iostream>

int main()
{ 
    struct S{void call();};
    if constexpr (HAS_METHOD(S,call))
        std::cout << "S has a call\n";
    else
        std::cout << "S does not have a call\n";

    if constexpr (HAS_METHOD(S,call2))
        std::cout << "S has a call2\n";
    else
        std::cout << "S does not have a call2\n";
}
```

#### Output[(Godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/z/GzY88b):

```
S has a call
S does not have a call2
```

### Explanation

#### Overload-based SFINAE

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/257382/7691729) answer, one can base SFINAE on overloading resolution between templated functions. Nice property of this is there is no need for specialization.

Here I used this approach for lambda's templated `operator()`. The code boils down to something like this:

```cpp
struct overload{
    template<class T>
    bool operator()(T * arg, decltype(&std::decay_t<decltype(*arg)>::call) ptr)
    {
      return true;
    }
    template<class T>
    bool operator()(T * arg, ...)
    {
      return false;
    }
};
```

When we call `overload{...}((S*)nullptr,nullptr)`, `T` is deduced to be `S` from the first parameter. This effectivelly gets rids of the templated code while still being in SFINAE context. The first (auxillary) parameter is necessary because lambdas do not have `template <typename S>` prior to C++20, also to obtain the type, one has to use `decltype(arg)`. `std::decay_t` is required because dereferencing a pointer returns a reference and `T&::call` is never valid syntax.

Note that one cannot use `std::declval` here because the context is evaluated. Pointer it is then, we won't actually dereference it anywhere. Now

1. If `S::call` is valid, the second parameter is of type "pointer to a member function with `call`'s signature". Of course `nullptr` is a valid value for any pointer. Because this overload is more specific than `...`(anything valid is), it is chosen and `true` is returned in `constexpr` manner.
2. If `S::call` constitues a syntax error, the first overload is discarded by SFINAE, the second still matches because `...` will match `nullptr` and the first argument could still be deduced. In that case we return `false`.

#### Overloading

To build the required set of overloads from lambdas in one expression, one can use parameter pack expansion and inheritance of methods which is exactly what this line from [`std::visit` helper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) does:

```
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
```

Then the macro itself just construct a temporary instance of this class, ctor is used to initialize the base classes = pass the lambdas. After that, the temporary is immedietely called with `((S*)nullptr,nullptr)` arguments.

Comment: Wow! That looks cool! Thanks! I'll need couple of years to figure out what happening here.

Comment: @Dmitry I will add some explanation, give me a few minutes. :)

Comment: If `call` is overloaded, i.e. `struct S{void call(); int call(int); };`, your method will not detect it. AFAICT there is no method in any C++ standard to do that.